# Why may not the colspan attribute be set to zero?

Tags: html, html-table

According to the `HTML5` description the attribute `rowspan` may have value 0. In this case the value zero means that the cell is to span all remaining cells of the given column in the row group.

However the value of `colspan` may not be equal to zero.

So a question arises what is the reason for such a restriction for the attribute `colspan`?

Comment: why do you think that colspan may not be equal to zero? can you provide reference to the source where you saw that restriction?

Comment: @Banana See here http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/tabular-data.html#attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements

Comment: well according to that page, those attributes `colspan, rowspan` must not be used to overlap cells, and according to [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan) this is the reason for the restriction on `colspan` in HTML5

Answer (score 2):

This is quoted from https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011Aug/0293.html but it explains the issue in detail.

> In HTML4, "colspan" and "rowspan" attributes of TD/TH elements has been allowed to have zero value ("0"):
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-colspan
>
> This is very useful when column or row number is unknown in advance.
>   It's harmful to force web-editors to calculate column or row number
>   manually while browser could easily do this automatically.
>
> There is a known rule in spec development: when there are two
>   independent implementations of a specification, then the specification
>   status is promoted to "recommendation" ("candidate" or "proposed").
>
> But there ARE already two (well, 1.5) working independent
>   implementations of zero colspan/rowspan:
>
> 1. Firefox (both zero colspan and rowspan are fully working)
> 2. and Opera (supports rowspan="0" and does not support colspan="0").
>
> So, zero value of colspan/rowspan is very good candidate to keep in
>   HTML spec and, moreover, to encourage rest browser vendors to
>   implement this useful feature as soon as possible.
>
> There are no serious reasons to remove zero values of colspan/rowspan
>   from the HTML specification. It's not something "unimplemented at
>   all", it's already quite usably implemented and should be kept intact
>   in the HTML spec.

Also the HTML5 spec (4.9.11) explicitly states that colspan shall be non-zero and rowspan can be zero along with what it means to be zero.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-colspan

The quick answer to why would be to say that the HTML5 spec explicitly states this restriction.  IMO I see no reason why browsers wouldn't reserve the meaning of zero to act the way Firefox has implmented other than to follow specification.

Comment: I tested colspan="0" in Firefox 116 and it does not appear to support colspan="0", so maybe they removed this capability. As far as I know, no browser currently supports colspan="0".

Comment: Interesting. As this answer was written in 2015 it is possible things have changed in the last 8 years. It is not uncommon to write updates to posts like this.